# A function related to divisior counting function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(n)$ be the divisor function. Let $d_{2}(n)=d(d(n))$, $d_{3}(n)=d(d(d(n)))$, $d_{4}(n)=d(d(d(d(n))))$ and so on... We're gonna define $f(n)$, the smallest number satisfies $d_{f(n)}(n)=2$. For example,

$$d(12)=6$$
$$d(6)=4$$
$$d(4)=3$$
$$d(3)=2$$

hence $f(12)=3$.

Can we find an asymptotic formula for $F(n)$ where

$$F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$$